# Sending XmlData in soap request using spring Integration ws

Tags: spring, soap, spring-integration, cdata

I have requirement to send `XmlData` in `CDATA` to soap request,format of xml is,

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <java:Request>
            <string>
                &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?  &lt;UserName&gt;CJI&lt;/UserName&gt;           &lt;PhoneNumber&gt;1234987456&lt;/PhoneNumber&gt;
            </string>
        </java:Request>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Am using Spring Integration ws outbound-gateway to call service, and I am getting below exception,
`org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element`, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
But this xml is tested in SOAPUI it's working.

Updated,
NOTE: the service am calling implemented using Axis1.2.

Am having some custom header tags.like  .
my exact xml will bind to tag ....

org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:345)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:148)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

2017-08-17 12:34:24,524 INFO  Found SoapFaultDetailElement {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname

Comment: improved formatting. corrected small grammar mistakes. Added extra tag

Comment: You need to show your configuration. You just need to send the contents; the gateway will add the soap envelope.

Comment: Would be great to see the whole StackTrace on the matter.

Comment: M-m-m, you show us the problem on the server side. How does it look on the client? And how exactly do you send? You can turn on logging for request to in the logs actual SOAP for sending: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#logging

Comment: And, please, study how to format questions here on SO: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174096/what-is-the-proper-way-to-format-a-posts-in-stack-overflow. It's hard to read without expected indenting